# value in the datagridview insert into datetimepicker

Tags: vb.net

i was trying to select a value in a DataGridView and insert it into a DateTimePicker. i have tried two codes but both of them are not working.
here is my code

this is the first code i have tried

```
   EditAccount.DateTimePicker1.Value = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(8).ToString
```

and this is the second code  i have tried

```
 EditAccount.DateTimePicker1.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(8).ToString)
```

can you help me???
thank

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need parenthesis '()' after `Cells(8).ToString` (in other words shouldn't you write `Cells(8).ToString()`